# Library of Django filters

Tags: python, django

I have created some [Django template filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/) that I constantly need.

I wanted to create a simple library to leverage them, but not sure what'd be the best way to import that.

Sample views.py code:

```
from django.template.defaulttags import register

@register.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key):
  return dictionary.get(key, '')
```

How can I split this function get_item to a say library.py file and still be able to register the templates only when this library is imported?

Thank you!

*Limitiations: only module-level imports; no wildcards or symbols import.*

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. Template filters are not registered in views.py; and there is no need to import then there either. Just load them in your template.

Comment: Maybe I need to change the question, but: 1) You can definitely register them in py side https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-custom-filters  ;; 2) Then my issue is how to choose when they apply (i.e. some vs all). |||| Currently, I register them on the views.py and I do not need to load them in the template at any point. Perhaps your alternative of loading them when needed is good. Could you provide further insight?

Comment: That link doesn't say anything about registering in the views. What it does say is that they must be registered in a file underneath templatetags/, and that you always need to explicitly load them in the template with the `{% load %}` tag. So I don't really know what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

django search for template tags under templatetags directory by default.
you can create this directory under your app directory like

```
-myapp
  + migrations
  - templatetags
    - __init__.py
    - library.py
  - __init__.py
  - admin.py
  - views.py
  - models.py
```

you can put all of your custom filter code in library.py and then in your template you first need to import library

```
#at the top or before using filter or tag
{% load library %}
```

and can directly use tags or filter that you have in library.py like

```
#for tag
{% custom_tag %}

#for filter
{{ xvy|custom_filter }}
```

Comment: This may work. I will test soon and confirmed and mark as answered. Thanks!

Comment: sure, this is right way for implementing custom tags and filter in Django.

Comment: Thanks! Worked :) I guess it was really basic, but it was very different to our current structure. Hence, the confusion.